# Determining whether virtual function is overloaded

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Lets assume we have

```
class Base
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        // some default implementation
    }
};

void bar(Base* b)
{
}
```

Is there a way to determine whether `foo` function of `b` object is overloaded from the `bar` function?

Comment: Are you sure that you mean *overloaded* and not *overridden*?

Comment: The word you're looking for is *overridden* btw. That is when a derived class reimplements the same virtual method. *Overloaded* means a method with different arguments but the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to *detect* whether a virtual function has been overridden.

Instead, in function `bar`, if you want the `Base` implementation call it like

```
void bar( Base* p )
{
    p->Base::foo();
}
```

and if you want a virtual call, binding to the implementation in the most derived class, call it like

```
void bar( Base* p )
{
    p->foo();
}
```

Comment: I need to fill up a struct which contains function pointers and then pass it to third party library function. For default behaviour I need to fill NULL in that struct. That is why I need to determine it

Comment: @ArmanHunanyan: That question doesn't seem related to the question you posted, sorry. For raw function pointers you need non-member functions or `static` member functions. Such functions cannot be `virtual`.

Comment: It related I need following in bar if (foo is overrided) {s.FOO_PTR = somting } else {s.FOO_PTR = NULL} then pass s to third party library

Answer (score 0):

A **non portable, very fragile** solution is this. I would not use my own solution in a real program. Was just curious enough to know if this can be done at all or not. I Would find out more elegant way to solve the "real problem". Your real problem, I assume, is something other than fiddling around to find if a function is overloaded or not. The '1' that you see in there has to be adjusted as per the layout of the base class. The 1 is the location of the function foo in the virtual table. Does require that you have an instance of Base class handy inside the bar function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Base { 
    public: 
        int l;
        virtual int foo3(){return 5;}; 
        virtual int foo(){return 0;}; 
};

class Base2 { 
    public: 
        virtual int foo2(){return 2;}; 
};

class Derived : public Base, Base2 { 
    public:
        int j;
        int k;
        virtual int foo(){return 1;}; 
        virtual int foo2(){return 5;}; 
};

void bar(Base* b)
{
    Base d;

    int* p;
    int* p2;

    p = (int*)&d;
    p2 = (int*)b;
    p = (int*)(*p);
    p2 = (int*)(*p2);

    int i = p[1];
    int k = p2[1];
    bool bOverLoaded;
    if(i == k)
    {
        bOverLoaded = false;
    }
    else
    {
        bOverLoaded = true;
    }

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Derived* p = new Derived();
    bar(p);
}
```